# Django collectstatic : change source of static files

Tags: django, collectstatic

I have a Django app, with a folder named `static`. When the app is deployed, `python manage.py collecstatic` is automatically ran and this folder is copied into `public/static` and everything works perfectly.
However, I want to run a gulp task before, that minifies my files and copy them into a folder named `dist`.
The question is : is there a way to specify to `collecstatic` command, in which folder are the static files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just configure the `STATICFILES_DIRS`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs

For further reading: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/integrating-front-end-tools-your-django-project/

Btw I would consider separating the front-end code and the backend code and serve the frontend from a CDN

Comment: It works. However, the folder `dist` is copied. However, the folder named `static` also is. Is there a way to remove this default behavior ?

Comment: Isn't it possible that the files from static were copied into public/static before you set up `STATICFILE_DIRS`?